# MongoDB + Morphia, how to avoid a lot of "xxx connections now open"

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, database

My MongoDB is getting a lot of "xxx connections now open" show at the console, i cant understand why, i created a DataStore Factory and im using Inject, why it dont close the connection? im using .getDB.requestDone() too...

where i get my DS:

```
public class DSFactory {

    Morphia morphia = new Morphia();
    Datastore ds = null;

    public DSFactory() {
        morphia.map(User.class);
        try {
            this.ds = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient("localhost"),
                    "userDB");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public Datastore getInstance() {

        return ds;
    }

}
```

my DAO:

```
public class UserDAO {

    @Inject DSFactory dsFactory;

    public void newUser(User user) {

        dsFactory.getInstance().save(user);
        dsFactory.getInstance().getDB().requestDone();

    }
}
```

every newUser i add, is a new connection in the MongoDB, so for 30new users, i will finish with "30 or more connections open", it just go to low number or 0 when i close the eclipse

Comment: Having a number of connections open shouldn't be a problem - the MongoDB API will effectively create a pool of connections that you can reuse.  Also, from the console some of those connections might be to other servers, if you're running in a replica set.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you inject UserDao somewhere, when that happens the container will try to create a new DSFactory. Each UserDao will try to create its own DSFactory, with each factory having its own Morphia datastore.

You probably one want one morphia datastore at a time, you could try to make the datastore into a @Singleton so each DAO gets the same DSFactory.

Comment: i tried, nothing changed, it create only one connection, but if the users logout or anything else, the connection stay open

Comment: requestDone() method is a Mongo api call, that should be abstracted by the morphia API, I don't think you need to call it